# Searching in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4

I have a page where user is provided with four **search** fields. I am suppose to take the intersection of the fields and display the results. However the user isn't required to fill in all of the fields.

In my controller i have the following code.

```
string subject = (string)Session[d.sessionSearchSubject];
string courseNumber = (string)Session[d.sessionSearchCourseNum];
string yearLev = (string)Session[d.sessionSearchYearLev];
string period = (string)Session[d.sessionSearchPer];


if (!(subject.Equals("") && courseNumber.Equals("") && yearLev.Equals("") && period.Equals("")))
{
   db.Courses.Where(a => a.subject.Equals(subject) && a.coursenumber.Equals(courseNumber) &&  a.period.Equals(period...
}
else if (!(subject.Equals("") && courseNumber.Equals("") && yearLev.Equals("")))
{
  // Query the database. 
}
else if (!(subject.Equals("") && courseNumber.Equals("") && period.Equals("")))
{
  // Query the database. 
}
else if (!(subject.Equals("") && yearLev.Equals("") && period.Equals("")))
...
```

As you can see there will be a lot of if statements. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this? i.e. a single query statement that ignores the field if its empty. Or if i can replace the empty string with something that would be equivalent to "any" ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break the results into four statements, corresponding to each of the four criteria:

```
var results = db.Courses;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject))
    results = results.Where(c => c...);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(courseNumber))
   results = results.Where(c => c...);
...etc...
```

keeps it clean and extensible, while also only attaching the conditions to the sql query that are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just put that logic into the single LINQ statement? Something like:

```
var results = db.Courses
    .Where(c => (c.subject == subject && c.subject != "")
        || (c.coursenumber == courseNumber && c.coursenumber != "")
        || (c.yearLev == yearLev && c.yearLev != "")
        || (c.period == period && c.period != ""))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have all of this logic in your Controller?

You should populate your View fields in the Model and then have a function in the Model to handle this logic for you. I.e. in your Model have a function called IsCourseValid() with the logic you provided.  You could then call this model method in the Controller and route to the appropriate view (What a Controller is intended to do), if you are just querying the database, do this via the Model.

The pattern you have currently is Fat Controller Thin Model, were you should have Thin Controller Fat Model (All logic is done in the Model and the Controller routes you to the correct view).

Tip:

Rather than doing `!subject.Equals("")` you could use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject)`